# How can I unpivot this data?

Tags: sql, pivot, teradata, unpivot

I have the following data:

| member_number | urban | rural | asthma | anxiety |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 2 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 3 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 4 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 5 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 6 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 7 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |

I want to unpivot the 'disease' columns "asthma" and "anxiety". I used the following query:

```
sel DISEASE, 
SUM(URBAN) URBAN, 
SUM(RURAL) RURAL,
COUNT(DISTINCT MEMBER_NUMBER) MEMBS
FROM final
UNPIVOT (
MEMBS FOR DISEASE IN (
CMS_ANXIETY AS 'ANXIETY',
CMS_ASTHMA AS 'ASTHMA'
)
)AS P
GROUP BY 1,2,3
ORDER BY DISEASE
```

This gives me the following (example data)

| DISEASE | URBAN | RURAL | MEMBS |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ANXIETY | 92000 | 8000 | 100000 |
| ASTHMA | 92000 | 8000 | 100000 |

The issue is my anxiety and asthma rows have the same number of members, which is not possible. Wondering how I fix.

Comment: Why `COUNT(DISTINCT MEMBER_NUMBER)`? Seems like `SUM(MEMBS)` (the column name assigned to the pivot value) would be what you want.

Comment: You probably just need to add `where membs = 1` to remove the `0` before aggregation.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't say what the key of your table is. I'm guessing member_number, in which case something like this should work:

```
SELECT 'ASTHMA' AS disease, SUM(urban) AS urban, SUM(rural) AS rural, COUNT(*) AS membs
FROM tbl
WHERE asthma = 1
UNION ALL
SELECT 'ANXIETY' AS disease, SUM(urban) AS urban, SUM(rural) AS rural, COUNT(*) AS membs
FROM tbl
WHERE anxiety = 1;
```

Comment: that works, but i was hoping to figure it out using unpivot, in case the  data were summed and member number was member count instead. i.e. no key.